# Como evitar o erro de "missing 1 required positional argument" quando um dos parâmetros é omitido

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho essa função em Python:

```
def v(m1,m2): 
    print(m1) 
    print(m2)
```

Ela dá um erro quando não insiro um dos parâmetros, por exemplo, inserido `m1 = [1,2,3]` e omitindo m2: `v([1,2,3])`

> missing 1 required positional argument

Como evitar este erro?

Answer (score -1):

Usando argumentos com valores padrão talvez seja o que você quer:

```
def f(v1=None, v2=None):
    if v1:
     print(v1)
    if v2:
     print(v2)
```

Assim, se você não passar v2, ele é `None` e portanto `if v2` é falsa, não executando o print dentro.

Comment: Esse tipo de comparação `if v1:` [não deve ser realizada em python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/499179/137387), vide também [PEP 8],(https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) a forma correta de realizar esse tipo de comparação é `if v1 is not None:`

Answer (score -1):

`Python` suporta `named arguments` ou seja voce pode definir um nome da variável nos argumentos da função:

```
def v(arg=None, arg2=None):
    if arg:
     // corre o codigo pro primeiro argumento
    if arg2:
     // corre o codigo pro segundo argumento


v(arg2="Oi")
```

Answer (score -1):

Coloque valores extras dentro dos parâmetros

Python 3.x tem suporte para isso

```
def v(m1=None, m2=None):
print(m1, m2)
```

Quando não se aplica nenhum valor, ele simplesmente retorna None, mas você pode colocar qualquer iterável dentro da mesma

Eis aqui o input:

```
v("Sus", "Amogus")
v("Sus")
v()
```

Eis aqui o output:

```
Sus Amogus
Sus None
None None
```

Espero ter ajudado.