# None em Python não deveria ser semanticamente igual ao Null de SQL?

Tags: python, sql

Isso faz sentido:

```
>>> if True==True:
...     print ('True')
...
True
```

Isso também:

```
>>> if False==False:
...     print ('True')
...
True
```

Mas isso para mim deveria retornar nada, mas retorna True...

```
>>> if None==None:
...     print ('True')
...
True
```

Meu entendimento era que `None` era com o `Null` em *SQL*. Nada é igual a `Null`, nem mesmo `Null`.

Comment: e qual "sql" seria esse? `mysql`, `sql-server`,  `oracle`? depende do driver/provider. `sql-server` tem um driver que retorna um tipo "DbNull" por exemplo :)

Comment: Cada linguagem implementa de um jeito, não há garantia de equivalência entre elas, somente o comportamento mais ou menos geral do valor nulo ser tratado de maneira especial em relação aos não-nulos. Veja que se fosse para ser igual ao SQL a linguagem de programação teria que ter o operador `IS` para fazer `IS [NOT] NULL` e não `== NULL`, as linguagens que conheço geralmente não têm isso. Nem o comportamento de comparação por igualdade é o mesmo entre as linguagens ou mesmo entre diferentes tipos de dados dentro de uma mesma linguagem, podendo ser sobrecarregado ou sobrescrito por exemplo.

Comment: Em python existe o IS, é possível comparar desta forma:  `None is None`. Inclusive é uma recomendação da PEP8.

Comment: Por que vc acha que deveria? Cada linguagem é criada de um jeito, e na prática cada uma cria as definições que quiser, da maneira que bem entender, com o significado que achar mais adequado (que diga o JavaScript, que tem `null` e `undefined`, e tanto `null === null` quanto `undefined === undefined` são `true` - pior, `null == undefined` é `true`, mas `null === undefined` é `false`) - No caso do Python, `None` é um valor. Claro, ele é usado para designar a "ausência de valor", mas ele em si é um valor, e por isso compará-lo com ele mesmo resulta em `True`.

Comment: @RicardoPontual, no padrão ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 7):

Esse comportamento ocorre assim porque a linguagem foi definida assim.

Na documentação oficial da linguagem [Modelo de dados: Nomes de métodos especiais](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) está escrito:

> Uma classe pode implementar certas operações que são chamadas por
> sintaxe especial (como operações aritméticas ou subscript e
> fatiamento), definindo métodos com nomes especiais. Esta é a abordagem
> do Python para sobrecarga de operador, permitindo que as classes
> definam seu próprio comportamento em relação aos operadores da
> linguagem.

Logo mais mais abaixo estão definidos os métodos de comparação:

> [**`object.__lt__(self, other)`**
>
> **`object.__le__(self, other)`**
>
> **`object.__eq__(self, other)`**
>
> **`object.__ne__(self, other)`**
>
> **`object.__gt__(self, other)`**
>
> **`object.__ge__(self, other)`**](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ge__)
> Esses são os chamados métodos de *“comparação rica”*. A correspondência
> entre os símbolos do operador e os nomes dos métodos é a seguinte:
>
> - `x<y`  chama `x.__lt__(y)`
> - `x<=y` chama `x.__le__(y)`
> - `x==y` chama `x.__eq__(y)`
> - `x!=y` chama `x.__ne__(y)`
> - `x>y` chama `x.__gt__(y)`
> - `x>=y` chama`x.__ge__(y)`

Substituindo a comparação `None==None` pelo respectivo método de comparação teremos:

```
>>> print(None.__eq__(None))
True
```

**Muito cuidado deve ser tomado** ao comparar `None` com outros valores:

```
>>> print(None == False) 
False
>>> print(None == True)
False
```

Isso ocorre porque o método de comparação `None.__eq__()` para outros valores que não sejam `None` não está definido e por padrão, `object` implementa `__eq__()` usando `is`, retornando `NotImplemented` no caso de uma comparação falsa: `True if x is y else NotImplemented`, implicando que qualquer coisa que não seja `None` comparada com `None` é `False`.

```
>>> print(None.__eq__(True))
NotImplemented
>>> print(None.__eq__(False))
NotImplemented
```

O reforça o alerta feito no [**PEP8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51):

> **Comparações com singletons como `None` devem sempre ser feitas com `is` ou
> `not` , nunca com os operadores de igualdade**
> Além disso, tome cuidado ao escrever `if x` quando você realmente quer dizer `if x not is None` - por exemplo, ao testar se uma variável ou argumento cujo padrão é `None` foi definido com algum outro valor. O outro valor pode ter um tipo (como um container) que pode ser falso em um contexto booleano!

Veja esse exemplo tirado do [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_ref_keyword_none2) que ilustra a situação:

```
>>> x = None

>>> if x:
...  print("Você pensa que None é True?")
... elif x is False:
...  print ("Você pensa que None é False?")
... else:
...  print("None não é True ou False, None apenas None...")
None não é True ou False, None apenas None...
```

E não adianta forçar uma classe para que emule o um valor lógico `None`:

```
>>> class teste():
...  def __bool__(self):
...    return None

>>> t = teste()
>>> print(bool(t))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(bool(t))
TypeError: __bool__ should return bool, returned NoneType
```

Comment: +1 ótimas referências :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual, você não sabe o quanto me é gratificante ler esse comentário. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

A linguagem define assim, veja:

A palavra-chave None é usada para definir uma variável nula ou um objeto. Em Python, a palavra-chave None é um objeto e é um tipo de dados da classe NoneType.

Podemos atribuir None a qualquer variável, mas você não pode criar outros objetos NoneType.

Fatos interessantes:

None não é igual a False.
None não é 0.
None não é uma string vazia.
Comparar None com qualquer coisa sempre retornará False, exceto o próprio None.

Comment: *"A linguagem define assim, veja"* e de onde diz isso? faria sentido colocar a fonte na pergunta

Answer (score 3):

Em Python, `None` é uma constante que representa [o único valor possível](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None) da classe [NoneType](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/types.html#types.NoneType).

Isto é, None é um objeto e sua classe NoneType adota o padrão [Singleton](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton). Quando você compara `None` com `None`, você está literalmente comparando o mesmo objeto. Só existe um None. É uma `keyword` que representa um valor.

Portanto, quando adotado esse padrão, comparações desse tipo não precisam de regras especiais para serem compreendidas. Se você compara um objeto com ele mesmo, faz sentido ela retornar `True`.